# Installing OpenSSL on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, openssl

Can anyone list a set of complete steps to install OpenSSL on Windows 7? I have tried a lot of things, but invariably, one or the other library is found missing. I know that OpenSSL depends on libxml2, pthread libraries and so on. I have tried downloading them from various sources, but I am a bit frustrated by a lot of errors that are showing up one after the other. If someone has done it before, it would be great if you can help me with the list of steps.

Comment: follow the instructions in my answer or read the complete `INSTALL.W32` file. I just did a build in VC 2005 and one in 2010 without *any* problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest OpenSSL source distribution (at the moment [openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz)), not the FIPS module (read [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html)), then follow the simple steps in the `INSTALL.W32` or `INSTALL.W64` file in the root of the source distribution. It's trivial. What you need is one of the supported VC++ versions and Perl ([Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) works fine for me) and you may opt in to using [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) for optimized code in a few places.

Depending on whether you use NASM it will be (without):

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=d:/openssl
```

or (with NASM):

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=d:/openssl
```

followed by:

```
ms\do_ms
```

and then after starting the VC++ command line ("Visual Studio XXXX Command Prompt") for the configured environment do from the root folder of the source distribution:

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

then:

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak test
```

and if that comes out clean ("passed all tests"):

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install.
```

I just ran it up this this step and it works flawlessly (as usual!) for the latest released OpenSSL (1.0.1c) under Visual Studio 2005. Re-trying with 2010 now.

**Edit:** just tried under the "Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)" and it works as well here.

**Note:** consider the remarks in the `INSTALL.W64` ("Caveat lector").

**Also note:** the FIPS module complements the OpenSSL distribution. You aren't actually compiling OpenSSL itself when you build the FIPS module!

Comment: I wouldn't call it "trivial".  Trivial would be running a batch file, or opening a pre-made solution/project file and pressing "Build".

Comment: @Adam: well, following these steps I consider trivial and it always works out of the box for me, which I can't say of many FLOSS projects.

Comment: When I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.0.0g for VS 2008 as a static library, I had to modify the Configure script to always use the `/MD` option to avoid multithreading crashes.  I also configured it with `disable-idea` to avoid potential patent issues with the IDEA algorithm.  There were also quirks with the header files (copied into the new `out32` directory) and the symbols file (`tmp32/lib.pdb`).

Comment: I tried the steps that you suggested. I downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.2, unpacked it, did a perl configure with strawberry and then tried ms\do_ms.bat. It gave me the error as shown in this image: http://i.imgur.com/A2Cre.png Any ideas why?

Comment: @Rajat: Any particular reason you are using the FIPS version?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: also the standard source distro or the FIPS one? Interesting nevertheless. I kinda skipped VS2008, but it's good to know these quirks. Whenever I had to use a particular algorithm I was usually cherry-picking the source files into my project(s) ;)

Comment: The standard distro.  For whatever reason (dunno if they've fixed this yet), the `Configure` script uses `/MD` when building the DLL (with `ntdll.mak`) but `/MT` when building the static library (with `nt.mak`).  I don't think it had anything to do with the particular version of VS.

Comment: @0xC0000022L nop, there was no reason. I somehow skipped the link to the source that you added in your answer. Applying your code on those sources works great! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this from a 'Developer's Command Prompt' for VS2012.

It worked fine.  Passed all tests.

I have ActiveState Perl on my path; I believe it is/was ahead of Strawberry Perl which is also on my machine.

-- 
HerbM