# How to install OpenSSL on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, openssl

I am trying to install OpenSSL to use it on my C++ project in Visual Studio Express 2012 under Windows 7. Refering to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483737/installing-openssl-on-windows-7-32bit), I have installed perl, but when I type the command in the windows cmd, I get the following error:

[[image]]

I have been all day trying to install it and the frustration of not having a decent documentation for dummies makes me want to give up. **Where do I have to type the command to install it?**

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Have you tried googling for a tutorial?

Comment: Yes sir I have looked everywere but there is no tutorial

Comment: Try running it in a directory where you unpacked the openssl source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can download bin file, example here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Then write two OPENSSL environment variable in windows(explain in photo), there is path variable.[image]

Comment: which is the right url to get the binaries from the above site?